# Android - How to set a list of webview with icon on right inside relative layout programmatically

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to figure out How to set a list of webview with icon on right inside relative layout programmatically. 
I have relative layout as parent in which i am adding a new relative layout programatically under this layout we need to put a icon on right of webview below is the code

```
 for(final OptionPOJO option: questionPOJO.getOptions()) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams mainparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            mainparams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

            final RelativeLayout linearLayout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(mainparams);
            linearLayout.requestLayout();

            final WebView optionview = new WebView(getContext());
            optionview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            optionview.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
            optionview.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
            optionview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                optionview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
                optionview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

            }
            optionview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            optionview.setClickable(true);
            optionview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            optionview.setBackgroundColor(0);
            optionview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            //optionview.getSettings().setStandardFontFamily("Roboto-Medium");
            linearLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_bg));


            optionview.getSettings().setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.NORMAL);
            optionview.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            optionview.setLongClickable(false);
            optionview.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
            String optionhead = "<head>" +
                    "<style>body {font-family: 'Lato';, font-size: 6.75pt;  background-color: yellow;    color: red; src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf');color:black;}</style></head>";
            String optionhtmlData = "<html>" + optionhead + "<body>" + option.getText() + "</body></html>";
            optionview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", optionhtmlData, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

            optionview.setLayoutParams(params);
            linearLayout.addView(optionview);


            button_layout.addView(linearLayout);
        }
```

Comment: What have you done so far? A vague question like this is going to be closed pretty quickly. Post what you've tried, and what you need help with.

Comment: updated the question